# How to define the ObjectMapper instance in new Algolia API v3

Tags: algolia

In the Java Client from previous algolia version (2.9) was pretty easy and documented how to customize the ObjectMapper to be used when indexing records. Now in v3 seems that there is no way or is not documented, so, anyone knows how do I set the ObjectMapper instance in algolia v3? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

With the Java client v3 you can still get the ObjectMapper like this: `Defaults.getObjectMapper();` You can find the default settings for the ObjectMapper [here](https://github.com/algolia/algoliasearch-client-java-2/blob/febbaeafd7fbdee4affc9856a4601947a1bd1443/algoliasearch-core/src/main/java/com/algolia/search/Defaults.java#L43) but be careful when modifying those because they fit Algolia APIs requirements.

Comment: yeah, but my question is how do I set the ObjectMapper in v3, not how to have access to it. In v2.9 it was possible.

Comment: Yes, you can't set a new instance in the v3 but you can customize the existing one.